# Calling an method from another class to an action listener in another class

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

I am trying to make my zoomIn/zoomOut button work on my GUI. I have 2(i have others but not needed to post) classes and the actionlistener/buttons are in one, and the zoom method.

I am having trouble calling my zoom method when the zoomIn/zoomOut button is pressed.

Class 1:(im already importing the GUI, didnt want to take up room on here)

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PartyParkingGUIPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
private final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 800;
private final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 600;
private final int DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH = DEFAULT_HEIGHT - 50;

//panels
private JPanel mapPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel setupPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel statusPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel setupButtonsPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel setupTextFieldPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();

//labels
private JLabel gridSizeLabel = new JLabel("grid size:");
private JLabel numCarsLabel = new JLabel("#of cars:");
private JLabel numParkingSpotsLabel = new JLabel("#parking spots:");

//buttons
private JButton randomGrid = new JButton("Random Grid");
private JButton readFile = new JButton("Read File");
private JButton resetGrid = new JButton("Reset Grid");
private JButton zoomIn = new JButton("Zoom In");
private JButton zoomOut = new JButton("Zoom Out");
private JButton start = new JButton("Start");
private JButton step = new JButton("Step");
private JButton pause = new JButton("Pause");


//text area and cityMap with scrollpane
private JTextArea status = new JTextArea("Enter grid size, #cars, #parking spots" +
        " \nClick on random button to generate random cars and spots" +
        " \nClick on reset grid to clear the grid",20, 20);
private CityMap cityMap;
private JScrollPane mapScroller = new JScrollPane(cityMap);
private JScrollPane statusScroller = new JScrollPane(status);

//text fields
private JTextField gridSizeField = new JTextField("10",12);
private JTextField numParkingSpotsField = new JTextField("0",12);
private JTextField numCarsField = new JTextField("0",12);

private int gridSize = ParkingSimulation.DEFAULT_GRID_SIZE;
private int numCars;
private int numSpots;
private ArrayList<Car> cars;
private ParkingSimulation simulator;

private boolean showPaths = true;
private int speedFactor = 1;
private boolean animate = false;
private int delay = 500; // milliseconds

/**
 * Set up the panel.
 */
public PartyParkingGUIPanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1200, 700));
    simulator = new ParkingSimulation();
    simulator.setGridSize(gridSize);
    cars = simulator.getCars();
    cityMap = new  CityMap(ParkingSimulation.DEFAULT_GRID_SIZE, DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH, simulator);
    cityMap.setShowPaths(showPaths);

    zoomIn.addActionListener(this);
    zoomOut.addActionListener(this);


    startAnimation();
}


....

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
 */
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource() == zoomIn){
        ??
    }
}

....
```

Class 2 that has the zoom method:

```
 public class CityMap extends JPanel
{
private int gridSize;
private final int DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH = 1024;
private int displaySize = DEFAULT_GRID_WIDTH;
private int blockSize;
private int carSize;
private int offset;
private int numBlocks;

private ParkingSimulation simulator;
private ArrayList<Car> cars;
private ArrayList<ParkingSpot> spots;

private boolean showPaths = false;
private boolean flag = true;
private final int PATH_THICKNESS = 2;


/**
 * Draw a city grid.
 * @param gridSize
 * @param displaySize
 */
public CityMap(int gridSize, int displaySize, ParkingSimulation simulator)
{
    super();
    this.simulator = simulator;
    this.cars = simulator.getCars();
    this.spots = simulator.getSpots();

    this.displaySize = displaySize;
    this.gridSize = gridSize;
    setParameters(gridSize);
    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(displaySize, displaySize));
    setDoubleBuffered(true); //makes drawing smoother
}


/**
 * Sets parameters for drawing the grid
 * @param size
 */
private void setParameters(int size) 
{
    numBlocks = size;
    blockSize = displaySize/(numBlocks + 1);
    offset = blockSize;
    carSize = blockSize/4;  
}


/**
 * Zoom by a factor (1 and higher)
 */
public void zoom(int factor) {
    setParameters(gridSize/factor);
}
```

Comment: You know you're adding a null variable, cityMap to your JScrollPane, since you're adding the variable before it has been given a CityMap object to refer to. For better help, in the future you'll want to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small compilable runnable program that only has code related to your problem or required to allow it to compile and run and no other. This will make it much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well one thing I noticed is both classes extend JPanel. I'm not entirely sure, but I think that can cause some form of runtime error within the program because it is interfering, but if that's not your issue, ignore that. In order for you to call a method, or anything public, from one class to another, you must create an instance variable of that class, or AKA, an object of that class. In order to do this, just type the name of the class you're using, such as

```
  CityMap objectOfCityMap = new CityMap();
```

then do this:

```
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
 {
    if(e.getSource() == zoomIn){
        // using the object to access the method or function from the other class
        objectOfCityMap.zoom(// factor amount);
    }
 }
```

Now, usually, you wouldn't have such long variables as objectOfCityMap, but this is just to show how the object is used. It is up to you on how to use the variables. I hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain how two JPanel extending classes "interfere" as I'm not familiar with that at all.

Comment: I was confused with something else at the time of my post

Comment: I'm a bit confused on how this is. If there are only 2 classes, with one containing the zoom method, how will the wrong method be called?    
Class 2 that has the zoom method:public class CityMap extends JPanel so CityMap is the needed object

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was wrong with my last comment, and have deleted it. My fear was not that the wrong method would be called, but that the right method on the wrong object would be called. He should only create one CityMap instance only, display it, and make sure that the `zoome(...)` method is called on this one visualized object. He would be in danger if he creates another CityMap non-visualized object anywhere just to call its methods.

Comment: That's alright :) We all make mistakes, and sometimes, ESPECIALLY with programming, we think too quickly on a piece of code, and it makes us judge too quickly, ya know? God Bless You!

Comment: On your CityMap objectOfCityMap = new CityMap(); it wants me to put something in the CityMap(?)

Comment: since you have parameters within the CityMap constructor, you must fill them between the () for your object. It would be CityMap objectOfCityMap = new CityMap(// int for grid size, // int for displaySize, // ParkingSimulation for simulator); and you just fill in the // with whatever value you have